# Django models & objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Is it possible to define your own query which will be executed when calling save method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply override the `save` method of your object. See the doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects.

Answer (score 0):

And once you have overridden the *save* method of your model you can perform raw SQL queries :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/